# I am getting this error when trying to create a project with Quasar CLI 'zsh: command not found: quasar'

Tags: node.js, npm, quasar-framework, quasar

I am at the beginning of a youtube tutorial [Twitter Clone with Quasar](https://youtu.be/la-0ulfn0_M)

and Im trying to install the **Quasar CLI**  after it looks like it installs successfully, then when I type the command

`quasar create <project-name>`

it gives me the not found error.

`zsh: command not found: quasar`

---

update -

I realized the quasar install is not even working because when I try to see the command list nothing comes up.

`npm install -g @quasar/cli`

this comes back

`npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/`

````
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/```

```changed 375 packages in 16s

36 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
dadecapo@Simons-MacBook-Pro quasar-project % quasar
zsh: command not found: quasar```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to update TLS 1.2
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

And maybe your Node.js along with npm. You may want to uninstall and reinstall Node.js by following these directions and then reinstall Quasar.

https://reactgo.com/uninstall-node-npm-from-macos/